# Local IP address not reachable when VPN is connected

Tags: networking, openvpn

I'm running a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with an OpenVPN client on it. If the VPN is not connected, everything works as expected.

If I'm connected to the VPN Server, the VPN Tunnel works as expected as well. But I can't reach my local LAN IP address anymore (even from the same switch). I don't get ICMP requests at all.

The network interface is up, and i the Raspberry can ping itself with the local IP address but not from the 'outside' (LAN).

Maybe I am at a loss, but I hope the problem is clearly described and you have an idea.

Comment: Does your VPN allow Split Tunnel?  It probably needs to.

Comment: This is expected behavior - you must specify `route` and `dhcp-option DNS` in your server _(preface with `push`)_ or client config: `route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` and `dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1` _([man page](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/#options))_

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, as [`route`](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/#network-configuration) and [`dhcp-option DNS`](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/#network-configuration) must be specified in the server **or** client config:

- **Server:** *(generally the most efficient, especially with >1 client)*

  ```config
  # Required:
    push  'route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0'
    push  'dhcp-option  DNS 192.168.1.1'

  # Also recommended:
    # NTP: (NIST)
    push  'dhcp-option  NTP 129.6.15.30'

    # Cloudflare DNS with malware blocking:
    push  'dhcp-option  DNS 1.1.1.2'
    push  'dhcp-option  DNS 1.0.0.2'
  ```
- **Client:**

  ```config
  route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
  dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1
  ```